# RDFS inference in Jena using ARQ (SPARQL)

Tags: java, sparql, jena, inference

The Jena docs here https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/index.html state that `createOntologyModel` includes a weak reasoner for transitive closure on the sub-class and sub-property hierarchies which is all I am looking for.  Starting with a simple model:

```
x:A rdf:type rdfs:Class .
x:A x:prop1  x:whatever .

x:B rdf:type rdfs:Class .
x:B rdfs:subClassOf x:A .
x:B x:prop2 x:other .

x:myInstance  rdf:type  x:B  .
```

I seek to query for `rdf:type x:B` and yield all properties for `B`and the superclass `A`, e.g.

```
( ?all = <x:whatever> ) ( ?props = <x:prop1> ) -> ( ?type = <x:A> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = <x:A> ) ( ?props = <rdfs:subClassOf> ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = <x:other> ) ( ?props = <x:prop2> ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = <rdfs:Class> ) ( ?props = <rdf:type> ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
```

I have been experimenting with this example for a bit.  It compiles and runs but only yields the properties for B and doesn't walk the `subClassOf`tree. I believe I have missed a basic setting or use of RDF schema that enables the reasoner to do its thing.  Any clues?

```
public class jena2 {
    private static void addRaw(OntModel m, String s, String p, String o) {
    m.add(ResourceFactory.createStatement(
          new ResourceImpl(s),new PropertyImpl(p),new ResourceImpl(o))
          );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(); 

    addRaw(model, "x:A", "rdf:type", "rdfs:Class");
    addRaw(model, "x:A", "x:prop1", "x:whatever");
    addRaw(model, "x:B", "rdf:type", "rdfs:Class");
    addRaw(model, "x:B", "x:prop2", "x:other");
    addRaw(model, "x:B", "rdfs:subClassOf", "x:A");
    addRaw(model, "x:widget", "rdf:type", "x:B");

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append("PREFIX x: <x:>");
    sb.append("PREFIX rdf: <rdf:>");
    sb.append("PREFIX rdfs: <rdfs:>");
    sb.append("SELECT *");
    sb.append("WHERE {");
    sb.append("  x:widget rdf:type ?type .");
    sb.append("  ?type ?props ?all .");
    sb.append("}");

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(sb.toString());
    try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;
        for ( ; results.hasNext() ; ) {
            QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution() ;
            System.out.println(soln);
        }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("epic fail: " + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: That code can never work: you can't add statements and simply use the prefixed URIs - how should the API know to which full URI to resolve? For example, you add `"x:A", "rdf:type", "rdfs:Class"` -> "rdf:type" will never be resolved to the correct URI `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type` . The same holds for all others. All of those without a protocol specified will be resolved to a local URI.

Comment: The same holds for the SPARQL query: `PREFIX rdfs: <rdfs:>` has nothing to do with the RDFS namespace, the full URI is needed

Comment: @AKSW Yeah; I was just experimenting with switching over to RDF.type and RDFS.subClassOf, etc.  I can def see why I need the full URIs for reasoning engine to do it's thing (since it is looking for them) but shouldn't my own classes get by with a simple x: prefix?

Comment: Yes, it should. I added some code that works for me below. You can check if that's what you need or if there is still something missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is **not** a full answer!)

As per comment above, some working code:

```java
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import org.apache.jena.query.*;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.*;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDF;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;

public class jena2 {

    private static void addRaw(OntModel m, Resource s, Property p, Resource o) {
        m.add(ResourceFactory.createStatement(s, p, o));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();

        Resource A = ResourceFactory.createResource("x:A");
        Resource B = ResourceFactory.createResource("x:B");
        Property prop1 = ResourceFactory.createProperty("x:prop1");
        Property prop2 = ResourceFactory.createProperty("x:prop2");
        Resource whatever = ResourceFactory.createResource("x:whatever");
        Resource other = ResourceFactory.createResource("x:other");
        Resource widget = ResourceFactory.createResource("x:widget");

        addRaw(model, A, RDF.type, RDFS.Class);
        addRaw(model, A, prop1, whatever);
        addRaw(model, B, RDF.type, RDFS.Class);
        addRaw(model, B, prop2, other);
        addRaw(model, B, RDFS.subClassOf, A);
        addRaw(model, widget, RDF.type, B);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        sb.append("PREFIX x: <x:>");
        sb.append("PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>");
        sb.append("SELECT * {");
        sb.append("  x:widget rdf:type ?type .");
        sb.append("  ?type ?props ?all .");
        sb.append("}");

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(sb.toString());
        try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
            ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
            for (; results.hasNext(); ) {
                QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
                System.out.println(soln);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("epic fail: " + e);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
( ?all = <x:A> ) ( ?props = rdfs:subClassOf ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = <x:other> ) ( ?props = <x:prop2> ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Class ) ( ?props = rdf:type ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = <x:B> ) ( ?props = rdfs:subClassOf ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Resource ) ( ?props = rdfs:subClassOf ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Resource ) ( ?props = rdf:type ) -> ( ?type = <x:B> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Class ) ( ?props = rdf:type ) -> ( ?type = rdfs:Resource ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Resource ) ( ?props = rdfs:subClassOf ) -> ( ?type = rdfs:Resource ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Resource ) ( ?props = rdf:type ) -> ( ?type = rdfs:Resource ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Resource ) ( ?props = rdfs:subClassOf ) -> ( ?type = <x:A> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = <x:whatever> ) ( ?props = <x:prop1> ) -> ( ?type = <x:A> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Class ) ( ?props = rdf:type ) -> ( ?type = <x:A> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = <x:A> ) ( ?props = rdfs:subClassOf ) -> ( ?type = <x:A> ) -> [Root]
( ?all = rdfs:Resource ) ( ?props = rdf:type ) -> ( ?type = <x:A> ) -> [Root]
```

It also returns the properties of RDFS class `A`

Comment: Confirming your recommendations work.  Many thanks, and shame on me for trying to cheat with junk URIs.  BTW, I think static String x is unused.